# NodeJS multer-s3 image upload req.file is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, multer-s3

I tried to upload a single image file to S3 via nodejs express server.
But, the request of middleware 'multer-s3' is undefined
I seperated the upload config code to 'upload.js' file and use it at routes.

This is my code.

```
// index.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var { upload } = require('../lib/upload');

var member = require("./member");
var admin = require("./admin");
var column = require("./column");

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express2' });
});

router.post('/uploadOne', upload.single('img'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    const image = req.file;
    if(image == undefined) {
        res
            .status(400)
            .json({
                responseMsg: 'no image'
            });
    } else {
        res
            .status(201)
            .json({
                responseMsg: 'success',
                file: req.file,
            });
    }
});

// 컬럼 관리자
router.post("/admin/login", admin.isAdmin);
router.get("/admin/verify", admin.verifyToken);
router.post("/admin/body", admin.getBody);

router.use("/api/member", member);
router.use("/api/column", column);

module.exports = router;
```

```
// upload.js
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3')
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
require('dotenv').config();

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

let upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: '************',
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE, 
        acl: 'public-read-write',
        metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
        },
        key: (req, file, cb) => { 
            console.log("success???? " + file);
            cb(null, 'users/' + file.originalname);
        },
    }),
    limits: { fileSize: 12 * 1024 * 1024 },
});

exports.upload = upload;
```

I tried all of the methods that came out by googleling, but it didn't work.
And, in upload.js, the log code in **key** option was not worked.
There seems to be a problem with the **upload.js** file itself or when calling the file, but I don't know what the problem is.
Could you tell me what is the problem in my code?

---

Edit 1 for upload.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3')
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
require('dotenv').config();

const endPoint = new AWS.Endpoint(process.env.AWS_S3_ENDPOINT);

// AWS.config.update({
//     endPoint: process.env.AWS_S3_ENDPOINT,
//     accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
//     secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
//     region: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION
// });

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    endPoint: process.env.AWS_S3_ENDPOINT,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION
});

let upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'bebenity-image',
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE, 
        acl: 'public-read',
        // metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
        //     cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
        // },
        key: (req, file, cb) => {
            console.log("success???? " + file);
            cb(null, file.originalname);
        },
    }),
    limits: { fileSize: 12 * 1024 * 1024 },
});

exports.upload = upload;
```

---

Edit 2 Log of **Upload**

```
Multer {
    storage: S3Storage {
        s3: Service {
            config: [Config],
            isGlobalEndpoint: false,
            endpoint: [Endpoint],
            _events: [Object],
            MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: EVENTS_BUBBLE],
            CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE],
            _clientId: 1
        },
        getBucket: [Function (anonymous)],
        getKey: [Function: key],
        getAcl: [Function (anonymous)],
        getContentType: [Function: autoContentType],
        getMetadata: [Function (anonymous)],
        getCacheControl: [Function (anonymous)],
        getContentDisposition: [Function (anonymous)],
        getStorageClass: [Function (anonymous)],
        getSSE: [Function (anonymous)],
        getSSEKMS: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    limits: { fileSize: 12582912 },
    preservePath: undefined,
    fileFilter: [Function: allowAll]
}
```

Comment: the configuration of AWS is missing.

Try this

```
const endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(AWS_S3_HOSTNAME);
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  endpoint,
  accessKeyId: AWS_S3_ACCESSKEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESSKEY,
});```

Comment: What does it means 'AWS_S3_HOSTNAME'?? It is a name of S3 bucket or https url? @Darkripper

Comment: endpoint (String|AWS.Endpoint) — The endpoint URI to send requests to. The default endpoint is built from the configured region. The endpoint should be a string like 'https://{service}.{region}.amazonaws.com' or an Endpoint object.

Comment: I edited the 'upload.js' like edit #1 in a question, but it is still **undefined**... @Darkripper

Comment: `endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint(process.env.AWS_S3_ENDPOINT)`

Update this

Comment: um... it is still undefined....I printed the **upload** varaible in `index.js` and the result is added to question.@Darkripper

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the aws API gateway , please do the following

Step-1

we need to Enable CORS in the API gateway, so click on the resource and then click on the Action button and Enable CORS. In CORS settings the value of Access-Control-Allow-Headers is '' and Access-Control-Allow-Origin is '' , and leave other settings as it is. Click on Enable CORS and replace existing CORS headers.

Step-2 Now, go to the settings of that API on which you are working. In settings enable Binary Media Types. Set the value of that field like this / , and Save the changes.